# Sharing state between circular imports

Tags: python, global-variables, python-unittest

**Background to avoid the XY problem**

I use `unittest` and run tests via discovery. I want the various tests to be able to read some variable `GLOB` that is set at runtime, which creates some circular imports. Say `runner.py` is the script that runs the tests and `test_a.py` one of the test files to be run, then:

- `runner.py` must import `test_a.py` (during discovery) to run the tests
- `test_a.py` must read `GLOB` which either lives in `runner.py` or in something that calls it

I think the `unittest` boilerplate is irrelevant to the problem (see examples below which do not involve it) but a solution specific to that problem would work for me.

I tagged "global-variables" but this might not be the good terminology (`somemodule.somevariable` would work fine if it was not for the circular import tricks).

**Question and demo files**

If module `a` imports module `b`, how can module `b` read a value from module `a` that can change after `b` imports `a`?

`a.py`:

```
import b
GLOB = 0

def get_glob():
    '''an attempt to ensure a call at runtime, but does not solve the problem'''
    return GLOB

def printy():
    print('Value in a:', GLOB, get_glob())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GLOB = 1
    printy()  # 1, 1
    b.printy()  # 0, 0 not 1, 1
```

`b.py`:

```
import a

def printy():
    print('Value in b:', a.GLOB, a.get_glob())
```

Reading around (e.g. [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)) I see mostly "avoid circular imports" but (cf. background) it cannot be avoided here. In my case I could read/write from disk (no multithreading or performance bottleneck) but that seems really awful.

Comment: Create module `c`?

Comment: @PeterWood It would not solve the circular import problem, unless you can see something I cannot...

Comment: You need to declare ‘global GLOB’ before you assign ‘1’ to it, otherwise it creates a new local name ‘GLOB’ in the ‘if __name__’ block.